# Use in operator in set of tuples python

Tags: python, performance, set, tuples, any

I have a problem trying to check if an element is part of a set in Python. (My set contains about 600K tuples of string.)

I'm searching for a solution that use the benefit of `in` operator to check if a value is element of a tuple of the set.

I've found solution like:

```
# S set of tuples, I'm checking if v is the second element of a tuple
any( y == v for (_, y) in S )
```

but this has a O(n) complexity.

The Python documentation says that the average complexity of the IN operator is O(1).

**EDIT**

**My problem is:** How to check if an element is the first/second/... element of at least one tuple of the set using the speed of `in` operator.

Comment: And your problem in here is ?

Comment: How to check if an element is the first/second/... element of at least one tuple of the set using the speed of IN operator.

Comment: Yes but doing this for every search has the same complexity of my code, because the creation of the new set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> average complexity of the IN operator is O(1)

That's correct for membership check in sets or any container that uses hash table for storing it's items like dictionary.

And its completely a different operation than following `in`:

```
for (_, y) in S
```

That `in` is just a part of the `for` loop syntax.

Also if you want to get the tuples that are contain a particular string you could use a list comprehension rather than the `any`:

```
[item for item in S if my_str in item]
```

If you want to take advantage of the `set`'s membership checking you should have sets instead of tuples but since they're not hashable you'd not be allowed to use them within a `set` in that case you can use `frozenset()` instead.

And in case you want to just check the existence of an item that meets a certain criteria you can go with following generator expression within `any`  :

```
any(my_str in item for item in S)
```

After all since your set completely has the potential of being a dictionary you can create a dictionary instead of set then just check the membership with `my_str in my_dict`. Your dictionary would be something like: `{'luca': 1, 'mario': 2 , 'franco': 3}`

Comment: yes, but I'm searching for something like
`code`('luca',_) in set([('luca',1),('mario',2),('franco',3)])`code`

Comment: @LucaDiLiello That's what I mentioned. But if you just want to check the existence the `any` would work but with a little change in the expression. Checkout the update.

Comment: The values in the set will not be changed after the first creation. I think that I will use a dict. Your solution is very good but not enough fast for my program because for each check it scan the entire set.

Comment: @LucaDiLiello I was about to mention that. Your set completely has the potential of being a dictionary you can create a dictionary instead of set then just check the membership with `my_str in my_dict`

Answer (score 4):

The complexity of a containment test depends on the *object type*, not the operator, because the operation is delegated to the container. Testing containment in a list is O(n), containment in a set is O(1).

However, you are not testing containment in a set, you are testing containment in a pile of tuples (where the container for the tuples *can't help*). Without further processing, you can't do better than O(n) here.

You could create and maintain separate datastructures, for example, where you track the separate values contained in your tuples as well as the tuples themselves, then test against those separate datastructures. That'd increase the memory requirements, but lower the computational cost.

You'd amortise the cost of keeping that structure up-to-date over the lifetime of your program (only increasing the constant cost of building the data structure slightly), and in return you get O(1) operations on your containment test. Only do this if you need to do this test multiple times, for different values.

Comment: "Testing containment in a list is O(n), containment in a set is O(1)." I did learn something today!

Comment: I'm interested in lowering the computational cost, I've have not memory problems. My tuples are couples of strings like (key,value). I could also transform it in a simple set of string (value), but I've the necessity to know the original key of this value.

Comment: @LucaDiLiello: then as you build your tuples, track the values in a separate set or dictionary (the latter can map the values back to keys too, should you need such a path).

Comment: @LucaDiLiello Sounds like you need a `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question as posed (note: This is not how you usually want to solve it, because it's guaranteed `O(n)` behavior, because the `in` operator does not have guaranteed `O(1)`, and in this case, never does).

You can use the `in` operator by mapping away the extraneous values from each `tuple`. Done with C-level built-ins, this will run faster than your `any` expression for large enough inputs, but the difference is small (maybe a 10% speed up for sufficiently large inputs where the value isn't there):

```
 # At top of file
 from future_builtins import map  # Only on Py2, to get lazy map
 from operator import itemgetter

 v in map(itemgetter(1), S)
```

This works because the `in` operator is implemented for arbitrary iterators as a lazy check similar to `any`, pulling a value at a time, comparing to `v`, and short-circuiting out if it finds a hit.

Like I said, this is `O(n)`; in the real world, if you might do this test more than once, you'd probably want to make a `set` of the target only and reuse it, or a `dict` mapping the target to the associated values if needed, to get `O(1)` checks. The other answers already cover this adequately.

Comment: Thanks you, but I'm using a dict because I've to do the check lots of time. I'm using it in a Map function in Spark over a very large dataset.